# Dendrogram: Grouping By Characteristics

Tags: r, tree, dendrogram

I have made dendrograms in the past following various online tutorials (e.g. https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/33876_1d7794d9a86647ca90c4f182df93f0e8.html)

**Goal:** Group `Exposures` by `Category`, and visualize this in a tree/dendrogram (e.g `ExpA` and `ExpD` would be grouped together since they are both `HeavyMetals`)

**Background:** I am trying to make a tree/dendrogram of the following:

```
Exposures = c("ExpA","ExpB", "ExpC","ExpD","ExpE", "ExpF")
Category = c("HeavyMetal","Hormone", "Pesticide", "HeavyMetal", "Pesticide", "Hormone" )
dataframe = data.frame(Exposures,Category)
```

I have tried the following:

```
hp = hclust(dist(dataframe))
plot(hp, labels = Exposures)
```

But I get an error message:

```
Error in hclust(dist(dataframe1)) : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 11)
In addition: Warning message:
In dist(dataframe1) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

I think the error message is because I do not have any numerical data but I am not sure.

**Question:** Is there a way to make a tree/dendrogram structure from a dataframe similar to the one above with the aforementioned goal in mind?

Thank you!

Comment: It seems that `hclust()` requires a dissimilarity matrix. Can you specify the dissimilarities between your observations?

Comment: I'm searching around google to answer your question but I'm not quite sure how to specify the dissimilarities between my observations. How do I do so?

Comment: https://artax.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/r-help/library/proxy/html/dist.html

Comment: Is the simil() in the following link what you are referring to?

Comment: I notice that all of your `Exposures` are distinct categories. This will not be a useful variable for measuring dissimilarity and for clustering the data.

Comment: Dissimilarities :
     ExpA ExpB ExpC ExpD ExpE
ExpB  1.0                    
ExpC  1.0  1.0               
ExpD  0.5  1.0  1.0          
ExpE  1.0  1.0  0.5  1.0     
ExpF  1.0  0.5  1.0  1.0  1.0

Metric :  mixed ;  Types = N, N 
Number of objects : 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
install.packages('cluster')
library('cluster')
dissimilarity <- daisy(dataframe)
hc = hclust(dissimilarity)
plot(hc, labels = Exposures)
```